# How to transform a field of the Requestbody before arriving at the handle with annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to make some changes in the body of some payloads in post method to change values ​​like uppercase or lowercase.
I've been researching what is closest to what I need is HandlerMethodArgumentResolver

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LowerCase {

}
```

---

```
@Data
@Builder
@Document
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Customer extends Model {

  @LowerCase
  private String email;

  @LowerCase
  private String username;
}
```

---

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<Customer> test(@RequestBody @Valid Customer payload) {
  System.out.println(payload);
  return ResponseEntity.ok(payload);
}
```

---

if I send this

```
{
  "email": "MYMAIL@GMAIL.COM",
  "username": "JIBARRA"
}
```

The result with need this

```
{
  "email": "mymail@gmail.com",
  "username": "jibarra"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@Data
@Builder
@Document
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Customer extends Model {

  @JsonDeserialize(using = ToLowerCaseDeserializer.class)
  private String email;

  @JsonDeserialize(using = ToLowerCaseDeserializer.class)
  private String username;
}
```

In ToLowerCaseDeserializer.java implement the logic to convert the incoming text to lowercase

```
public class ToLowerCaseDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7527542687158493910L;

    public ToLowerCaseDeserializer() {
        super(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return _parseString(p, ctxt).toLowerCase();
    }

}
```

Comment: extends StdDeserializer<String>  public ToLowerCaseDeserializer() {
        super(String.class);
    } @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return _parseString(p, context).toLowerCase();
    }

Comment: It is deserialize not serialize. I have edited my answer and also given the ToLowerCaseDeserializer  impl

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426150/trim-input-values-in-thymeleaf-using-spring-mvc/55985848#55985848

Answer (score 1):

You can make changes to the request body using Spring **message converters** ,define a **custom converter** for the **Json converter**(which converts a **JSON** to Object) and add it like below for spring-boot.

To write a message converter, extend the Spring AbstractHttpMessageConverter(for a new custom converter), and override the three methods readInternal(),writeInternal() and supports() .

> Spring uses HttpMessageConverters to render @ResponseBody (or
>   responses from @RestController). You can contribute additional
>   converters by adding beans of the appropriate type in a Spring Boot
>   context. If a bean you add is of a type that would have been included
>   by default anyway (such as MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter for
>   JSON conversions), it replaces the default value. A convenience bean
>   of type HttpMessageConverters is provided and is always available if
>   you use the default MVC configuration. It has some useful methods to
>   access the default and user-enhanced message converters (For example,
>   it can be useful if you want to manually inject them into a custom
>   RestTemplate).

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
@Bean
public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
    HttpMessageConverter<?> additional = ...
    HttpMessageConverter<?> another = ...
    return new HttpMessageConverters(additional, another);
}

}
```

Similar post : [Spring boot how to custom HttpMessageConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172163/spring-boot-how-to-custom-httpmessageconverter)

Reference for answer :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-responsebody-rendering

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-message-converters

Comment: thank for reply, this my solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426150/trim-input-values-in-thymeleaf-using-spring-mvc/55985848#55985848

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in the controller. I don't think the message converter is the place for converting data

Converting the case implies some sort business constraint or rule. As such, I think you would want that happening explicitly in the code of the controller rather than some property of an annotation. Then way if the requirements change (because they always do), you know where and how to change it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426150/trim-input-values-in-thymeleaf-using-spring-mvc/55985848#55985848